# concatenation of values of columns into separate column

Tags: sql

I want to concatenate the values of same column into separate column

Suppose there are columns called types and text

```
TYPES    TEXT 
A        This is a 
B        This is b
C        This is c
```

I want the desired output as:

```
Con
This is c | This is a 
This is c | This is b
```

Comment: What are the things that you've tried? Also your questions still seems vague

Comment: Please paraphrase and format your question

Comment: How do you decide which values to concatenate?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Why is "This is c" repeated twice, but no a or b?

Comment: its like I wanna concatenate the values of the same field into separate column and the columns are from the same table

Comment: I wanna concatenate the values from Type column A and C

Comment: Very unclear what you want. Add more sample data and a better explanation.

Comment: suppose there is a column called type with data A,B,C  and column called text with data   this is a,this is b,this is c.  this is c| this a associated with A in type column and this is c| this b associated to B in type column

Comment: both the column are from same table

Answer (score 0):

I think joining table with self can help you:

This is pseudo code

```
select t.text || tb.text || tc.text
from t
inner join t tb using(types)
inner join t tc using(types)
```

So, to concatenate A and C columns you can try following:

```
select t.text || tc.text
from t
full outer join t tc using(types)
where t.types = 'A' and tc.types = 'C'
```

Comment: and output is  this is c this c

Comment: As I said this is pseudo code , you need to refactor it to your RDBMS

Comment: you're  welcome, could you mark the answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(t1.text ,' | ', t2.text ) from tablename t1
inner join tablename t2
on t1.types <> t2.types
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a811b/4)